# Oracle SQL query missing month

Tags: sql, oracle

Could you help me with the issue below?

I need to have all MARKS (total of 33) on final table, but the query is only showing 23 due to there were no flight for any specific month / year (for ex: 7/2020).

I have got a join with table TT1 (that have a column with the last flight date log) together table AF (that have flight date column filled only if there are flights logged).

Please find below the query I have built so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT,
    TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT,
    extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) MO_FLIGHT_DATE,
    extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) YR_FLIGHT_DATE,
    
    CASE WHEN extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END MO,
    CASE WHEN extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END YR,
        
    TT1.FLEET,
    TT1.MARKS,
    TT1.AIRCRAFT_SN,
    ROUND(Max(( ( AF.total_ac_flight_hours ) * 60 + ( AF.total_ac_flight_minutes ) ) / 60),2) TOTAL_FH,
    Max(AF.total_ac_cycles) TOTAL_FC,
    ROUND((( ( Sum(AF.flight_hours) * 60 ) + Sum(AF.flight_minutes) ) / 60), 2) MONTH_FH,
    ( Sum(AF.cycles) ) MONTH_CY,
    COUNT(DISTINCT AF.flight_date) DAYS_IN_SERVICE
        
FROM
    (SELECT
        extract(month from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied ) MO_LAST_FLIGHT,
        extract(year from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied) YR_LAST_FLIGHT,
        AM.ac_type || '-' || AM.ac_series FLEET,
        AM.ac MARKS,
        AM.ac_sn AIRCRAFT_SN
    
    FROM
        ODB.ac_master AM
    
    WHERE
        AM.status = 'ACTIVE'
    
    GROUP BY 
        extract(month from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied),
        extract(year from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied),
        AM.ac_type || '-' || AM.ac_series,
        AM.ac,
        AM.ac_sn

    ORDER BY
        extract(month from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied) DESC,
        extract(year from AM.last_date_flight_log_applied) DESC,
        AM.ac ASC
    )TT1
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    odb.ac_actual_flights AF
    ON TT1.MARKS = AF.ac

WHERE
    TT1.FLEET NOT LIKE '%SIM%' AND
    TT1.FLEET = 'ATR72-600' AND
    CASE WHEN extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END = '2' AND
    CASE WHEN extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END = '2020'
    
    
GROUP BY 
    TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT,
    TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT,
    extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE),
    extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE),
    CASE WHEN extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(month from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END,
    CASE WHEN extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) >= TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT THEN TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT ELSE extract(year from AF.FLIGHT_DATE) END,
    TT1.FLEET,
    TT1.MARKS,
    TT1.AIRCRAFT_SN

ORDER BY
    TT1.MO_LAST_FLIGHT DESC,
    TT1.YR_LAST_FLIGHT DESC,
    TT1.MARKS ASC
```

Comment: That's a big query to debug, and we don't have a clue about the structure of your tables. You should probably try and build a *minimum* reproducible example that demonstrates the issue, so one can look into it more efficiently.

Comment: Probably you want to pregenerate some calendar table with all months and then left join your query to it. But if you simplified your query and added sample minimized input, it would be much more convenient to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As the question contains no specific test data and actual/expected query results, please have a look at the following demo, which may help.  Suppose we have 2 tables: one for "scheduled" flights, one for "actual" flights.

TABLES

```
create table TT (  -- "scheduled" flights
  scheduled date
, aircraft varchar2( 16 )
);

create table AF (  -- actual
  flightdate date
, aircraft varchar2( 16 )
);

-- actual flights
-- aircraft 1: every month
-- aircraft 2: months 2 and 3 only
-- aircraft 3: month 3 only
-- NO FLIGHTS in month 4
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-01-17', 'aircraft_1' ) ;
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-02-15', 'aircraft_1' ) ;
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-16', 'aircraft_1' ) ;
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-02-17', 'aircraft_2' ) ;
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-15', 'aircraft_2' ) ;
insert into AF ( flightdate, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-16', 'aircraft_3' ) ;

-- schedule for months 1-4:
-- every aircraft is scheduled to do one flight per month
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-01-10', 'aircraft_1' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-02-25', 'aircraft_2' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-07', 'aircraft_3' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-12', 'aircraft_1' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-01-25', 'aircraft_2' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-02-07', 'aircraft_3' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-02-12', 'aircraft_1' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-03-25', 'aircraft_2' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-01-07', 'aircraft_3' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-04-12', 'aircraft_1' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-04-25', 'aircraft_2' );
insert into TT ( scheduled, aircraft ) values ( date '2020-04-07', 'aircraft_3' );
```

Query

If you write a query containing a LEFT JOIN, and include the year/month in the ON clause (as you had mentioned "flight for any specific month" in your question), you may get closer to the solution eg

```
select 
  to_char( TT.scheduled, 'YYYY-MM' ) tt_ym
, TT.aircraft tt_aircraft
, TT.scheduled
, AF.flightdate
, case when AF.flightdate is null then 'flight cancelled' end comment_
from TT left join AF 
  on to_char( AF.flightdate, 'YYYY-MM' ) = to_char( TT.scheduled, 'YYYY-MM' ) 
    and TT.aircraft = AF.aircraft
order by tt_ym, tt_aircraft
;

     TT_YM    TT_AIRCRAFT    SCHEDULED    FLIGHTDATE            COMMENT_ 
__________ ______________ ____________ _____________ ___________________ 
2020-01    aircraft_1     10-JAN-20    17-JAN-20                         
2020-01    aircraft_2     25-JAN-20                  flight cancelled    
2020-01    aircraft_3     07-JAN-20                  flight cancelled    
2020-02    aircraft_1     12-FEB-20    15-FEB-20                         
2020-02    aircraft_2     25-FEB-20    17-FEB-20                         
2020-02    aircraft_3     07-FEB-20                  flight cancelled    
2020-03    aircraft_1     12-MAR-20    16-MAR-20                         
2020-03    aircraft_2     25-MAR-20    15-MAR-20                         
2020-03    aircraft_3     07-MAR-20    16-MAR-20                         
2020-04    aircraft_1     12-APR-20                  flight cancelled    
2020-04    aircraft_2     25-APR-20                  flight cancelled    
2020-04    aircraft_3     07-APR-20                  flight cancelled
```

DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e36d90cfbe456835b7c06a72641b849b).

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Great insights!!

Comment: You are welcome.  What could also be of interest for you: have a look a the following site, section "Data densification for Reporting": docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm

Comment: And: if you found the answer to be useful, please "upvote" it :-)